# How do I generate a python dictionary comphrension that generates keys as a range function of the values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I can generate a dictionary comprehension

```
{str(i):0 for i in range(5)}

{'0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0}
```

How do I modify it so it so that the resultant dictionary is as below:

```
{'0-1': 0, '2-3': 0, '4-5': 0, '6-7': 0, '8-9': 0}
```

I've had some initial success with what you would expect

```
bins = {i*2:0 for i in range(5)}
```

but past that I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{str(2*i)+'-'+str(2*i+1):0 for i in range(5)}
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code will return the desired output:

```
{'{}-{}'.format(i, i+1): 0 for i in range(0, 2 * 5, 2)}
```

Comment: Python 3.6+, [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) can be used : `{'{}-{}'.format(i, i+1)` --> `f'{i}-{i+1}'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```py
In [2]: {f'{i}-{i+1}':0 for i in range(0, 10, 2)}
Out[2]: {'0-1': 0, '2-3': 0, '4-5': 0, '6-7': 0, '8-9': 0}
```

This `range(0, 10, 2)` will return `0, 2, 4, 6, 8`. Starting from 0 to 10 by twice. So `i` value always be `0, 2, 4, 6, 8`, then `i+1` is `1,3,5,7,9`.